# Single shot time not working inside pyqt4 QThread

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qthread

I am trying to use single shot timer inside QThread but it's not working. Following is the code I am using:

```
class thread1((QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.Timer1 = None

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def timerPINNo(self):
        print "Timer completed"

    def run(self):
        tempVal0 = getData()
        if tempVal0 == 0:
            self.Timer1 = QtCore.QTimer()
            self.Timer1.timeout.connect(self.timerPINNo)
            self.Timer1.setSingleShot(True)
            self.Timer1.start(5000)
        else: pass
```

The problem I am facing is that after time out the *timerPINNo* function never gets called. The single shot is working when using normally but not when I am calling it from QThread. Where I am making mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because if the run method finishes executing the thread finishes its execution and therefore it is eliminated and consequently the timer also. The solution is to keep the run method running for it, `QEventLoop` must be used.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class thread1(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Timer1 = None

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def timerPINNo(self):
        print("Timer completed")


    def run(self):
        tempVal0 = getData()
        if tempVal0 == 0:
            self.Timer1 = QtCore.QTimer()
            self.Timer1.timeout.connect(self.timerPINNo)
            self.Timer1.setSingleShot(True)
            self.Timer1.start(5000)
            loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
            loop.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
   th = thread1()
   th.start()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The better solution is to not override the `run` method at all so that you're not preventing the inbuilt event loop of the `QThread` from running.

Comment: Can you explain me better